# vue router unexpected redirection

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Here is my routing code:

```
// export so we can use in components
export var router = new VueRouter();

// define routes
router.map({
    'home': {
        component: Home,
        auth: true
    },
    'login': {
        component: Login,
        auth: false
    }
});

// fallback route
router.redirect({
    '*': 'home'
});

router.beforeEach(function (transition) {
    console.log("here!");
    console.log("beforeeach auth.user.authenticated: "+auth.user.authenticated)
    if (transition.to.auth && !auth.user.authenticated) {
        // if route requres authentication i.e. auth:true in routes
        // and isn't authenticated
        transition.redirect('login');
    } else {
        transition.next();
    }
});
// expose the whole thing on element with 'app' as an id
router.start(App, '#app');
```

Here is my `auth/index.js`

```
export default {
    user: {
        authenticated: false
    },

    login: function(context, creds, redirect) {
        this.user.authenticated=true;
        console.log("logged in!");
        router.go('/home');
    },

    logout: function() {
        this.user.authenticated=false;
        console.log("logout");
        router.go('/login');
    }
}
```

My Nav.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="top-nav-bar" v-if="user.authenticated">
     // other code here....
                   <ul class="notification user-drop-down">
                    <li><a href="#" @click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
                   </ul>
     // other code here ...
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import auth from '../services/auth';

    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                user: auth.user
            }
        },
        methods: {
            logout: function () {
                auth.logout();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I click the logout button, it redirects to `localhost:8080/#!/home`
But my `auth.logout()` has `router.go('/login')` . So it should redirect to the login Controller!

When I manually put in browser `localhost:8080/!#/home` then it correctly redirects to the /login page. So why does the logout button stays at /home (and I see an empty page and no console errors!)?

**EDIT:**

I am using vue 1.0.7 and vue-router 0.7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting this error because I was using an `<a>` tag.

`<li><a href="#" @click="logout()">Logout</a></li>`

So it was going to `#` url(which led to the fallback route) instead of invoking the `@click`. 
Hence I had to use the `@click.prevent` to prevent this default  behavior of anchor tag:

`<li><a href="#" @click.prevent="logout()">Logout</a></li>`

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is

```
router.go
```

the go method accepts an integer as parameter ( see http://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html )

I think you actually want a

```
router.push({ path: "/login"})
```

Comment: I am using vue 1 and vue router 0.7.5. Just updated my question